# QT creator tutorial: Itemstyle invalid

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Running the Currencyconverter tutorial "itemstyle" in the following line is underlined with red:

```
ItemStyle.class: "title"
```

with an error "invalid property name"

How to fix this error?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the invalid property name if you import the Ubuntu.Components as Theming:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1 as Theming
```

However, the fact that the editor shows it underlined with red does not mean it doesn't work - it works just fine even if it's red. I think this is related to the fact that all of the stuff is alpha/beta currently and not really that well integrated.